# Generate OBR file for my JIRA plugin

Tags: maven-2, jira, jira-plugin, obr

I have developed a JIRA plugin ,I need to know how I can generate a .obr file instead of a JAR file .
Can somebody help me with this ,
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get started, have a look at [How to Get Started with OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Technology/HowOSGi), and read on of the tutorials:

> - [EclipseCon Tutorials](http://www.eclipsecon.org/2006/Sub.do?id=176) - A tutorial given by Thomas Watson and Peter Kriens at EclipseCon 2006. [Note: Tutorial content has been moved to [Subversion]](http://www.osgi.org/svn/public/trunk/eclipsecon/2006)
> - [The Server Side](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=OSGiforBeginners): OSGi for Beginners - A hello worldtutorial.
> - [Javaworld: OSGi tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-osgi1.html) - A beginners tutorial.
> - [Glyn Normington's Hello World](http://underlap.blogspot.com/2007/01/creating-osgi-bundle.html) - Probably the smallest (but complete) Hello World on OSGi.
> - [Neil Bartlett's getting started](http://njbartlett.name/bndtools_intro.html) Neil Bartlett wrote a Getting Started series on EclipseZone that uses Equinox.
> - [OSGi development with Eclipse Equinox - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/OSGi/article.html) Lars Vogel's tutorials
>     about using OSGi with Equinox.
> - [OSGi and Equinox Jumpstart](http://eclipsesource.com/en/downloads/presentations/osgi-and-equinox-jumpstart/) Jeff McAffer's and Chris Aniszczyk's 6 part webinar.

You can find more information and how-to's at [Altasian's OSGi and Spring Reference Documents](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/PLUGINFRAMEWORK/OSGi+and+Spring+Reference+Documents)

check also [this post](http://njbartlett.name/2011/09/12/why-obr.html) for info about OBR